# Hashmap Access from another class

Tags: hashmap, rule

I want to access Hashmap from another class for Rule writing how can i do that?

Class Nov{

```
public static main()
...
public static HashMap<Object, Object> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject) throws ParseException {
 Set<Object> set = jsonObject.keySet();
    Iterator<Object> iterator = set.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = iterator.next();
         if (jsonObject.get(obj) instanceof JSONArray) 
           {
                 getArray(jsonObject.get(obj));

           }  
          else {

              } 

}
```

Comment: HashMap<Object, Object> parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject)  want to call this another class so that i can parse hashmap as per the usecase

Comment: i tried this but not able to proceed further
Class newclass{   
Nov x = new Nov();       

      private void main() {
           HashMap<String, Integer> people = x.parsejson(JSONObject jsonObject);}}



link refered:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197899/accessing-a-hashmap-from-a-different-class